# Xtend force java 7 language level

Tags: java, intellij-idea, xtend

I am using Xtend in intellij from the [Xtend-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8073?pr=). My project language level is set to Java 8 and Xtend compiles fine to Java 8 (e.g. using lambda expressions).

For specific reasons, I need Xtend to generate Java 7 code, without changing the language level of my remaining project (Java 8).

In the Xtend project settings I can set the language level, however this option is ignored. I believe it is ignored because the remaining project still uses JDK 8 and the Java 8 language level.

Is there an option to force Xtend to use a different (lower) language level than the source?

Comment: Java 7 code is perfectly compatible with Java 8 code.  What proof do you have that this setting is being ignored?

Comment: It generates lambda expressions. The generated code is used on the GWT client side, which does not support the new Java 8 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478195) in the Xtend-Compiler which prevents crosscompiling to a lower version of the JDK than the one in the classpath of the project.

Example:

```
#[ 42, 43 ].forEach[ println(it) ]
```

If the project if configured to have Java-8 classes in the **classpath**, the generated Java-Code will automatically use the Java-8 **API** (the `forEach` default method of `Iterable`, `Consumer`, ...)

This is *idependent* of any source/target level settings.

Answer (score -1):

I don't many details on the above question but assuming if the project is Maven based then you can target compilation in the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.5.1</version>
 <configuration>
  <source>1.7</source>
  <target>1.7</target>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```